# jenkins not accepting xunit xml log from casperjs

Tags: javascript, testing, jenkins, frontend, casperjs

I got phantomjs and casperjs working on my jenkins server. 
The test are executet and successfull. But here is the thing:

Casperjs logs its result in an log.xml file. And I thought I can show the content of that xml file on my jenkins webUI. I found that xunit plugin for jenkins, but it does not work as expected:

> [37;42;1mPASS 12 tests executed in 22.324s, 12 passed, 0 failed, 0
>   dubious, 0 skipped.    [0m

As you can see the test are successfull

> [32;1mResult log stored in ../../build/frontendtests/log.xml
>   [0m Publishing Clover coverage report... Publishing Clover XML
>   report... Publishing Clover coverage results... Recording test results
>   [xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record. [xUnit] [INFO] - Processing
>   AUnit-3.x (default) [xUnit] [INFO] - [AUnit-3.x (default)] - 1 test
>   report file(s) were found with the pattern
>   'build/frontendtests/log.xml' relative to
>   ' for the testing framework
>   'AUnit-3.x (default)'. [xUnit] [ERROR] - The result file
>   ' for
>   the metric 'AUnit' is not valid. The result file has been skipped.
>   [xUnit] [INFO] - Fail BUILD because 'set build failed if errors' option is activated.

Jenkins build fails, since my log.xml does not work with AUnit. I also tried JUnit and JSUnit. Same result. But I don't understand it. casperjs exports xunit xml files and I installed the xunit plugin. But the plugin does not read my log.xml.

DO you have any solution? Maybe my jenkins settings are wrong? Any ideas?

Thanks...

Here is my log.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   <testsuites duration="3.859">
    <testsuite name="Checking the portal search for http://www.xxx.de/suche/jeans" tests="1" failures="0" errors="0" time="2.687" timestamp="2013-08-20T14:12:55.953Z" package="./execute_search_tests">
      <testcase name="Subject equals the expected value" classname="./execute_search_tests" time="2.687"></testcase>
      <system-out></system-out>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Checking the portal search for http://www.xxx.de/suche/asjdfkshjkfhdsjkafhkjasd" tests="1" failures="0" errors="0" time="1.172" timestamp="2013-08-20T14:12:55.954Z" package="./execute_search_tests">
      <testcase name="Subject equals the expected value" classname="./execute_search_tests" time="1.172"></testcase>
      <system-out></system-out>
    </testsuite>   </testsuites>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: you have configured your XUnit post build action with the AUnit option. This is for Ada unit tests.

But I also tested the XUnit plugin together with the JUnit option, and it still failed. I even [enabled more logs](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12900?focusedCommentId=159687&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-159687), but that didn't help.

```
Aug 21, 2013 12:00:05 AM com.thalesgroup.hudson.plugins.xunit.service.XUnitService errorSystemLogger
SEVERE: [xUnit] - The result file '/Users/lacostej/.jenkins/workspace/test-casperjs-xunit/log.xml' for the metric 'JUnit' is not valid. The result file has been skipped.
Aug 21, 2013 12:00:05 AM com.thalesgroup.hudson.plugins.xunit.service.XUnitService warningSystemLogger
WARNING: [xUnit] - The file '/Users/lacostej/.jenkins/workspace/test-casperjs-xunit/log.xml' is an invalid file.
Aug 21, 2013 12:00:05 AM com.thalesgroup.hudson.plugins.xunit.service.XUnitService infoSystemLogger
INFO: [xUnit] - [JUnit] - 1 test report file(s) were found with the pattern 'log.xml' relative to '/Users/lacostej/.jenkins/workspace/test-casperjs-xunit' for the testing framework 'JUnit'.
```

Yet when I made some tests using the "JUnit test result report" plugin and parsing went fine.

**Update**

As you found out, the problem is [with the casperjs file using attribute duration instead of time for testsuites nodes](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!topic/casperjs/n1tbi0K9Tnk). Xunit is more strict than standard junit about it.

My suggestion:

1. use the standard JUnit parsing, it works
2. if you really want to use xunit, you got to get it fixed, then report a bug for the xunit parsing. Here's the test case config I used: https://gist.github.com/lacostej/6287937
3. or maybe try using the custom style together with an XSL. You will still have to debug and know why your XML isn't accepted.

I would pick option #1 or #2.

Comment: Thanks, I picked #1. It was easy to set up. Here a link for another possible solution for the same question: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!topic/casperjs/n1tbi0K9Tnk (I didn't try it, but it sounds reasonable, but it might be a little dirty solution.